# jQuery .load() doesn't load script

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery `.load()` function like in load_to.html page

```
$('#targetID').load('/load_from.html #bodyPart, script')
```

However, this doesn't seems to be loading javascript from load_from.html page. Is there any way, I can load javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From jQuery's [documentation for `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

> jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML
>   property to parse the retrieved
>   document and insert it into the
>   current document. During this process,
>   browsers often filter elements from
>   the document such as `<html>`, `<title>`,
>   or `<head>` elements.

To load scripts, you should create `<script>` elements yourself in the document's `<head>`:

```
$('<script>', {src: 'js_file.js'}).appendTo('head');
```

Perhaps you can request a list of scripts to load from the server with ajax:

```
$.post('scripts_to_load.json', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.scripts.length; i++) {
        $('<script>', {src: data.scripts[i]}).appendTo('head');
    }
});
```

Comment: what would happen if the script tags were moved inside the #bodyPart element?

Comment: hmm, interesting... looking at the unminified source, the load function strips any script tag to prevent security errors in IE (// inject the contents of the document in, removing the scripts // to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE) (line 6240)

Comment: I have some inline scripts embded in load_from.html file.

Comment: @Krishna, I know - but unfortunately you can't load those in this way. You will need to load those inline scripts separately using the method I have describe, or `.getScript()` as suggested by dane.

Comment: Thanks for @Ben, @Box9. Btw I am loading fragmentation of by  $('#targetID').load('/load_from.html #bodyPart, script'). however his seems inclding <div id="bodyPart">. Is there any way to exclude <div id="bodyPart"> from load_from.html page

Comment: However using this, $('<script>',{src:'js_file.js'}).appendTo('head'); , when I checked on firebug, the script was not appended on the head, instead a GET request for this script was found in console. What is the meaning of this?

Answer (score 8):

how about using .getScript()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/