# Html Adding Script Jquery

Tags: php

this script

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("selector").load('loader.php')

})
```

loader.php

```
echo '<script src="ads.rels.js"></script>';// here coming .swf file
```

how can we work like this think

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .load() doesn't load script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467221/jquery-load-doesnt-load-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just load the javascript without using PHP?  Like this:

```
$.getScript("ajax/test.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
  console.log( textStatus );
})
```

Ref.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/