# jquery: function doesn't work from external page

Tags: jquery

I have a page that loads external html from the same domain, this(external) html page has another jquery code that for some reason refuse to work.

the page:

```
$("#success").click(function () {     
$(this).load("testpage.html", function(response, status, xhr)
...
```

external
testpage.html:

```
<div id="hidediv">
<a id="hidelinks" href="#">hide</a> <br />
text <br />
</div>

<script>
$('#hidelinks').click(function() {
    $('#hidediv').slideUp();
});
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: [jQuery .load() doesn't load script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5467221/944681)

Comment: You have $(this).load - if $('#success') is not a div e.g. a button or <a> tag, it would try to load into that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't load content from another domain because of the same origin policy.  You must use JSONP (and the other domain must provide it).

Answer (score 0):

You will not get this to work. It's a security feature to prevent XSS.

Maybe an iframe is an option for you?

Hope this helps

**Edit**
Ok, this something differnent.

Try changing your code
to

```
$(function(){
      $('#hidelinks').click(function() {
       $('#hidediv').slideUp();
   });
});
```

As this script has to wait for it DOM to be ready, too.